# How to scroll to a row in UITableView on first open

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView which holds a number of choices and allows user to select one of these choices. I mark the selected row with a checkmark accessory.

On an iPad, I open this in a Pop over on click of a button and the table view shows up with one of the rows checked. But sometimes this checked row is not on screen and one needs to scroll to get to it. I would like to scroll to this checked row when I open the pop over. I have tried doing a scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: in viewDidAppear but I find that viewDidAppear is called before any call to cellForRowAtIndexPath and the scrolling to selected row doesn't happen

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear called");

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    //currentSelectedIndexPath is a correct index path
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:currentSelectedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];        

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` just before scrolling in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: thanks, it does seem to work. But I am still not clear why is it needed? what happens when we do this?

Comment: @AmaltasCoder This forces the `UITableView` to get created and populated. You should call this method whenever you change the data for the tableView.